# REST - Strongly typed models

Tags: typescript, rest

I'm thinking about using a new model structure for my new api.

### Current state

I have `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` endpoints. Just forget about `DELETE` because it only takes a query parameter and has no model.

Those three endpoints all use the same model:

```
Car Model 

id: string | undefined;
manufacturer: string;
date: Date;
```

### Problem

When requesting a single car via the `GET` endpoint I theoretically could get a car without a `id`. So when I want to pass the `ID` to the `DELETE` endpoint I always need to check that the ID is not undefined.

### Possible solution

Providing different models for each HTTP method.

```
1. Car Model for POST request

id: string | undefined;
manufacturer: string;
date: Date;
```

```
2. Car Model for [PUT request, GET response, ...]

id: string;
manufacturer: string;
date: Date;
```

I also want to provide `PATCH` request I would also need this model

```
3. Car Model for PATCH request

id: string | undefined;
manufacturer: string | undefined;
date: Date | undefined;
```

### Questions

1. In total I would need three different models. But is that really worth going for and considered as a 'Good Practice'?
2. If that is a 'Good Practice' how should I name the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only got one model, called `Car`. It looks like this.

```
interface Car {
  id: string;
  manufacturer: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

Calling the other ones models is missing the point. At no point are those *partial* things stored in a database or in any sort of long-term storage. They're transient.

As you've already noticed, for `PUT` requests and `GET` responses, you're always receiving or returning (respectively) a fully defined object, so `Car` suffices for that.

Your proposed `PATCH` type is simply [`Partial<Car>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype). No need for a new type; TypeScript provides this type for you. This can also be used if you want to have a query interface, where a `GET` request gives you a partially-defined car and finds all matches.

For your proposed `POST`, you want an optional `id` but all other fields required. That's a bit more complex but should look something like

```
Omit<Car, "id"> & { id?: string }
```

which reads "remove the `id` field from the `Car` object and replace it with this optional one". [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is another utility type that TypeScript provides us with.

You can give these things names. In fact, I encourage you to. I'm always an advocate of naming more things, as it provides more documentation in the code itself as to why we're doing what we're doing.

```
type PatchCar = Partial<Car>;
type PostCar = Omit<Car, "id"> & { id?: string };
```

`PatchCar` screams "`Car` but for `PATCH`" in its name, while `Partial<Car>` doesn't really say *why* we've just made all of the fields optional.

The important thing is that there's one representation of the `Car` model: namely the interface called `Car`. Everything else is just an offshoot of that. If we add fields to `Car`, we only have to update it in one place, not several. Remember, [don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for! Would you also recommend adding `readonly` to IDs or properties that are actually `readonly`?

Comment: Shouldn't `PatchCar` also exclude readonly information like the `ID`?

Comment: Yeah, I think both of those suggestions are good ideas. You should be able to do the latter using `Omit` like I did in `PostCar`.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's almost always a bad practice to have multiple variants of the same model structure in your code. (see [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

TypeScript [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) can possibly help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by model. By REST you work with view models or in other terms representations. You can have as many different representations as you want to. A simple example is managing numbers with your REST API and having binary, decimal and hexadecimal representations. You can name them as Number / Representations  / Binary, Decimal, Hexadecimal. As of your data storage, REST has nothing to do with it, it is a webservice, not a database. You can store your data in the file system, or even in cookies, it does not care.

Comment: I'm not talking about data storage as a problem. When you want to consume an api then you need to provide information in a specific schematic aka. model. I'm looking for a convention, standard or "best practice" that can help me naming those schematics (models)

Comment: @dewey Check schema.org and other standard RDF vocabs. https://schema.org/ There is a Hydra vocab for REST, which is exactly for describing the API. It is the closest to fulfilling the uniform interface constraint afaik. https://www.hydra-cg.com/ From a practical aspect what you are describing is sort of HTML forms and views. It is hard to describe them with the same view model, though not impossible.